# Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild'

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm making an android app with Ionic and I updated some plugins and now it doesn't build the apk, so I started a new app to see which is the plugin that is causing the problem, it's firebase.
When I run "ionic cordova build android" I get this message:

```
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.0.0,17.0.0], [17.2.0,17.2.0]], but resolves to 17.2.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

I know that it's firebase because it's the only plugin I have in my new app.

I created a virtual machine to start from 0, followed the instructions in https://ionicframework.com/getting-started and created my app:

```
ionic start app sidemenu
```

Added cordova:

```
cd app
npm install -g cordova
```

Added android platform and builded apk (to see if it works, it does)

```
ionic cordova platform android
ionic cordova build android
```

And added the firebase

```
npm install firebase @angular/fire --save
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
npm install @ionic-native/firebase
```

After succesfully adding the firebase I tried to build the apk but I got the error I show above.

```
Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.7 (C:\Users\jmir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.9.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
@angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 5 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.4.0
native-run  : 0.2.8

System:

NodeJS : v12.2.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm    : 6.9.0
OS     : Windows 10
```

Cordova plugin ls

```
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```